# How increase or decrease in quantity using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here i am having one table and in that table i having one column `quantity` increment as decrement after that i want to take that value, i don't how to do, i tried lot of time but it is not happening , if anyone means please update your code.I posted what i tried i don't know `increment` and `decrement` part of this section.

```js
function addToCart(product_id, obj) {
  var qty = $(obj).closest('tr').find('#txtAcrescimo').val();
  console.log(qty);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-xs">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th class="text-right center">Quantity</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item-row">
      <td>
        <p>Sandisk</p>
      </td>
      <td class="text-right center" title="Quantity">
        <center>
          <div class="input-group quantity-div">
            <button type="button" class="pls altera"> - </button>&nbsp;
            <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" class="left-mob" id="txtAcrescimo" style="width: 60px;height: 23px;padding-left: 20px;">&nbsp;<button type="button" class="pls altera acrescimo" onclick="addToCart('12',this)"> + </button>
          </div>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item-row">
      <td>
        <p>TRANBO </p>
      </td>
      <td class="text-right center" title="Quantity">
        <center>
          <div class="input-group quantity-div">
            <button type="button" class="pls altera"> - </button>&nbsp;
            <input type="text" name="quantity" value="4" class="left-mob" id="txtAcrescimo" style="width: 60px;height: 23px;padding-left: 20px;">&nbsp;<button type="button" class="pls altera acrescimo" onclick="addToCart('16',this)"> + </button>
          </div>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

> I have tried like this

```
function addToCart(product_id, obj){
        var qty = $(obj).closest('tr').find('#txtAcrescimo').val();
        console.log(qty);

        var $input = $("#txtAcrescimo");

        // Colocar a 0 ao início
        $input.val(1);
        if ($(this).hasClass('acrescimo'))
            $input.val(parseInt($input.val())+1);
        else if ($input.val()>=1)
            $input.val(parseInt($input.val())-1);

        console.log($("#txtAcrescimo").val());
 }
```

Comment: Look at parseInt - also don't have inline event handlers and you need unique IDs

Comment: Also put the productID in the name of the input, no need to pass it in the button since you use relative selectors

Comment: @ Jaromanda, check now i posted what i have tried

Comment: @ mplungjan,Kindly updaye your code on my snippet

Comment: Just click edit, scroll down and edit snippet and paste your code. You need to have a classes acrescimo and decrescimo on the buttons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have changed a Class of minus button and please try this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.pls.altera').click(function() {
       var curr_quantity = $(this).prev().val();
       curr_quantity = parseInt(curr_quantity)+1;
       $(this).prev().val(curr_quantity);
       alert('Product Name : '+$(this).parent().parent().parent().prev().text());
   });
   $('.pls.minus').click(function() {
       var curr_quantity = $(this).next().val();
       if(curr_quantity != 0) {
           curr_quantity = parseInt(curr_quantity)-1;
           $(this).next().val(curr_quantity);
           alert('Product Name : '+$(this).parent().parent().parent().prev().text());
       }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-xs">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th class="text-right center">Quantity</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item-row">
      <td>
        <p>Sandisk</p>
      </td>
      <td class="text-right center" title="Quantity">
        <center>
          <div class="input-group quantity-div">
            <button type="button" class="pls minus"> - </button>&nbsp;
            <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" class="left-mob" id="txtAcrescimo" style="width: 60px;height: 23px;padding-left: 20px;">&nbsp;<button type="button" class="pls altera"> + </button>
          </div>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item-row">
      <td>
        <p>TRANBO </p>
      </td>
      <td class="text-right center" title="Quantity">
        <center>
          <div class="input-group quantity-div">
            <button type="button" class="pls minus"> - </button>&nbsp;
            <input type="text" name="quantity" value="4" class="left-mob" id="txtAcrescimo" style="width: 60px;height: 23px;padding-left: 20px;">&nbsp;<button type="button" class="pls altera"> + </button>
          </div>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ,Your code not working fine like , `-` also decrement happening,suppose `0` we should disable the button

Comment: You can stop decrement when it reached 0.

Comment: can you please your code update

Comment: @KaniR, Updated you can check now

Comment: @ Gur Janjua, while `incrementing` or `decrementing` time i have to take the `Product Name` also but here not there kindly update this please

Comment: @KaniR, Updated you can check now

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.number-spinner button', function() {
  var btn = $(this),
    oldValue = btn.closest('.number-spinner').find('input').val().trim(),
    newVal = 0;
  newVal = (btn.attr('data-dir') === 'up') ? parseInt(oldValue) + 1 : (oldValue > 1) ? parseInt(oldValue) - 1 : 0;
  btn.closest('.number-spinner').find('input').val(newVal);
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 spinner-block">
  <div class="number-spinner">
    <div class="input-group number-spinner">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number btncartsniper" data-type="minus" data-dir="dwn"><span class="fa fa-minus fa-sm"></span></button>
      </span>
      <input name="quantity[]" class="form-control input-number Snippper_qty" value="0" type="number">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number btncartsniper" data-type="plus"  data-dir="up"><span class="fa fa-plus fa-sm"></span></button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="number" id="num">

<script>
function abc() {
    document.getElementById("num").stepUp();



}
</script>
```